# FastAPI sharing SQLAlchemy session across threads when using synchronous functions

Tags: multithreading, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Noob question about normal `def` path operations functions, dependencies and SQLAlchemy. Quoting the example here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency, where the db sessions is created in `get_db()` (synchronous) and used in `create_user()` (synchronous). According to https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#very-technical-details, synchronous dependencies and path operation functions are executed in a thread pool, so does this mean the same DB session object is effectively shared across 2 different threads (assuming it's not the same thread that gets re-used across the dependency and path operation function)? Could this be problematic since SQLAlchemy sessions are not thread-safe?

I may be completely misunderstanding how this works, so any clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: After thinking about this more I think this should be fine because session is accessed sequentially (not concurrently) even though it's potentially by two different threads. But I'm assuming using the `session` like the following would be problematic?

```
async def func(s: Session):
  loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_func, s)
  await loop.run_in_executor(None, some_other_func, s)
  ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Session objects are not thread-safe, but in SQLAlchemy you actually have multiple connections, because SQLAlchemy has a connection Pooling system by [default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html) so your every other SessionLocal that you define will have own connection

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

So, **No connection is shared**, eveything is seperated, also SessionLocal closed just after the request. So it's not thread-safe but i don't think it could be problematic.

[image]

Imagine you have a endpoint and it gets 2 requests at the same time, so in this case, different connections will answer your request. Even it's not concurrent, it acts like concurrent with Pooling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the problem I had was not really about whether a single session is shared by two requests (which as you explained above, is not), but rather whether a single session is shared by two threads that handle the same request (and think they do but it should be ok since the access is sequential).

Comment: @ljiatu Ups, i think [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-thread-safe) will explain the things perfectly, if it doesn't i 'll try my best again :)

Comment: Yeah I read that before, so I think it means the example I had at the end of my question would be unsafe, correct?

Comment: Exactly, if you want thread-safe session check out `scoped_sessions`